# php decode chinese words

Tags: php, decode

I'm trying to decode some chinese words like:

\u592a\u5e73\u9053\u5bf5\u7269\u8a3a\u6240\uff0c\u9999\u6e2f\u4e5d\u9f8d\u65fa\u89d2\u81ea\u7531\u90537\u865f\u5730\u4e0bB\u8216\u3002

How do I decode the above chinese words by using Php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `mb_convert_encoding`. [More details - mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
$str = '\u592a\u5e73\u9053\u5bf5\u7269\u8a3a\u6240\uff0c\u9999\u6e2f\u4e5d\u9f8d\u65fa\u89d2\u81ea\u7531\u90537\u865f\u5730\u4e0bB\u8216\u3002';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}, $str);
```

**Result:**

```
echo $str;//太平道寵物診所，香港九龍旺角自由道7號地下B舖。
```